# what this sql does

Tags: sql, mysql, database, string

I have this as a sql statement. What does it do

```
IF(`table`.`field1` IS NULL, 
   '', 
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `table`.`field1`  ASC SEPARATOR ',')
   ) AS `MyNewFields`,
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help you if you gave us the context it appears in.

Comment: @frustratedwithformsdesigner nice id :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The portion of the SELECT clause you provided will return a zero length string if the `TABLE.field1` value is null.

If the value is not null, it will use the [GROUP_CONCAT function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to return a comma delimited string based on the `TABLE.field1` values for the group by clause (which we can't see).  Example output:

```
MyNewFields
-------------
a,b,c
```

Comment: +1 was writing approximately the same as you, when i noticed your answer

Answer (score 0):

Inside the IF statement, it's checking to see if Field1 of Table is null, and returns an empty string if it is.  If not, it calls the GROUP_CONCAT extension method that returns a comma separated, ascending ordered list of the distinct values from Field1 in the Table.